# Bukkit config.yml connection

Tags: java, bukkit

Alright, I'm trying to program a bukkit plugin and I need to have values from the config file, I've looked up the tutorial at
http://wiki.bukkit.org/Configuration_API_Reference#The_Configuration_Object but this gave me no assistance.

So my code for connect.java is this:

```
package com.live.AlioGenerica.netherflight;

import java.util.Set;

import org.bukkit.configuration.file.YamlConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

public class users {
    this.getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);

    public static Boolean getValue(Player p) {
        this.getConfig().getBoolean(p);
        return true;
    }

    public static Object setValue(Player p, Boolean v) {
        conval.myConfig().set("users." + p + ".boolean", v);
        return true;
    }
}
```

config.yml is this:

> users:
>     username: false
>   userother:true

and etcetera.

How in the world do I connect, I couldn't find anything. I know this is a mess, because I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Also, if anyone could show me how to indent on code-references it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To indent on code references you have to use space. It's kinda inconvenient but that's how it goes sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

I myself create Bukkit plugins on my own. The `YamlConfiguration` is quite easy to use. You can use the method

```java
public void set(String option, Object value)
```

to set a certain configuration option (`option`) to a specified value (`value`) and

```java
public Object get(String option)
```

and others to get a previously set value. To find all the methods you can use, look them up in [Bukkit's JavaDoc for `YamlConfiguration`](http://jd.bukkit.org/rb/apidocs/org/bukkit/configuration/file/YamlConfiguration.html).

If you want to save your `YamlConfiguration`, use

```java
public void save(File f) throws IOException
```

Besides that, you should work on your coding. Here's a improved version of your code as it is now.

```java
package com.live.AlioGenerica.netherflight;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.bukkit.configuration.file.YamlConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

public class Users {
  private static YamlConfiguration config = null;
  // some code

  // this method has to be static if you want to use it
  // in another static method
  public static YamlConfiguration getConfig() {
    // load the configuration if it hasn't been loaded yet
    if(config == null) {
      config = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration("path/to/config.yml");
    }
    // some code
    return config;
  }

  // this will return the boolean you want to get
  public static Boolean getValue(Player p) {
    return getConfig().getBoolean("users."+p.getName());
  }

  // use this code to set the value
  public static void setValue(Player p, Boolean value) {
    getConfig().set("users."+p.getName(), value);
  }

  // save the configuration
  public static void save() {
    try{
      config.save(new File("path/to/config.yml"));
    }catch(IOException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

If there are any questions left, just let me know.

@EDIT: Just realized you wanted to save a boolean for a player so that it looks like this in the configuration.

```java
users:
  player: true
  anotherplayer: false
  andsoon: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so to deal with the config, the first thing you want to do is actually have a config and put it in the correct place. It looks like you have a config, so you just have to make sure it's located in the resource section of your plugin. After you do that, then you can start dealing with it in your code.

First you want to actually get the config. You do that with this code.

```
    FileConfiguration config = plugin.getConfig();
```

Simple enough. Now what you want to do is make it so that the plugin will retrieve the values in the config.

```
    config.options().copyDefaults(true);
```

Finally, you just check to see if the config has been saved in you plugin's data folder.

```
    if (!(new File(plugin.getDataFolder() + config.getName()).exists())) {
        plugin.saveDefaultConfig();
    }
```

After you do all those things, you can retrieve the actual values of the config with:

```
    plugin.getConfig().getBoolean("username");
```

Comment: `config.options().copyDefaults(true);` would not be the best way to do it if you want to save your #notes in the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Using this.getConfig() can only be done from the main class that extends JavaPlugin.

You can use the getConfig() and methods built in with that if you do something like this:

```
public class Example {

   MyPlugin plugin;

   public String getSomethingFromConfig() {
      return plugin.getConfig().getString("path");
   }

}
```

Thats the Easiest way, In My Opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Having a configuration file to get reference variables is very easy to do once you know how to do it. Starting this off you need actually *have* a `config.yml` in your `src` folder of your project. If you are not in Eclipse, I would suggest switching to it to do this easier. Just make a file called config.yml. You can put your variables inside of here that I see you have already did.

After this you need to *create* the config file when the server starts.

You would need to call a method on your onEnabled method from your main class. You can pull the `getConfig()` method from other classes also, that I will show you how below.

Since everytime the console enables it will do this method you will need a `try/catch` operation:

```
try 
{

} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The catch is if something goes wrong it will print a stackTrace to console. Inside of the `try` you will create the `config.yml`. To do this you will need to make a file variable inside of the `try`:

```
File config = new File(getDataFolder(), "config.yml");
```

Before you can make the config there has to be a data folder for the config to be stored in. To make this data Folder you will need to first see if it is there:

```
if(!getDataFolder().exists())
{
    getDataFolder().mkdirs();
}
```

After making the data folder you will need to check if the config.yml is already there, and if not create it.

```
if(!config.exists())
{
    getLogger().info("Config.yml not found, Creating");
    saveDefaultConfig();
}
```

Having the `saveDefaultConfig();` method will make sure to save your `#notes` inside of your config file to tell the user what each variable does. This is the best way to save your config file upon creating it. If the config already exists you can put an else and say that it is already there, but this is not necessary.

Make sure all of that is inside of a method that is called in the `onEnable()` method from your main class. Now that your config is created you can easily get variables from the *main class* by using the method `getConfig()`

You can also do this from other classes that I will tell you how to do soon. You can grab any variable from the config by doing `getConfig().get ...` and past here you can get many things such as `strings, integers, booleans, etc...` It will then give you a string to find the variable from. This will be the variable name inside of your config.

To use the `getConfig()` method from other classes you will need to use a constructor. You will need to call an instance from the main class to do this.
In your other class make a constructor like this:

```
[MainClassName] plugin;

public [OtherClassName]([MainClassName] instance)
{
    plugin = instance;
}
```

The `plugin` variable will be your instance from the main class. You can use `plugin.getConfig()` to get the config now.

However, when you register events/commands you will need to match this constructor. Just put `this` to match the constructor when registering events/commands.

I also notice that you have variables inside of variables. To get the variables inside of the variables you need to get a Configuration Section:

```
for(String key : instance#getConfig().getConfigurationSection([config path]).getKeys(false))
```

The String *key* will be the variable inside of the variable. Since this is iterating, it will get all the variables inside of the variable with the one string `key`. To get the value of the `key` variable you would just make a boolean/int/string or whatever is inside and get it by doing:

```
[String/boolean/int/etc...] value = instance#getConfig().get[Int/String/Boolean/etc...]([first config path]+"."+key)
```

This is all you need to know about configuration files.